# Silverlight Response.Redirect() using mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, navigation

I'm working on a project where there are 2 kinds of users(user and admin). Now when I log in I want to redirect the users to Views/UserHomePage.xaml and the admins to Views/AdminHomePage.xaml.

So what is the Response.Redirect() from ASP.NET for Silverlight? I do all the navigation in my viewModel just so you know :)

Thx

Comment: How are you navigating from your login page?

Comment: I don't, my first page is the login page. This is where im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You need Silverlight Navigation Framework.
Here are posts on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [www.silverlightshow.net](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx).
You must use code like this

`this.Frame.Navigate(new Uri(goToPage, UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: Ofcourse there will be other solutions. It will be useful if you says which part of this solution is not acceptable for you. In that case may be someone will give other solution.

Comment: It is working now!

HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("http://localhost:51311/COVR.TimeRegistrationTestPage.aspx#Admin/AdminHome"));

This is the way to solve it